# Why is the Hammer of Fate called the Hammer of Firebeard in Dragonsayer (Warhammer)?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, gotrek-felix

In the *Gotrek & Felix* book *Daemonslayer* the party travel to Karak Dum to recover the Hammer of Fate:

> 'Yes, the huge hoard of Karag Dum was lost when the city fell, and all the treasure was lost. And of all the treasures that were lost, the most precious were the **Hammer of Fate**...'

Source: *Daemonslayer: The Great Plan* by William King

---

The book *Dragonslayer* is set immediately after *Daemonslayer* where they call the same hammer the Hammer of Firebeard:

> [Felix's] hand still hurt from the burns he had taken wielding the **Hammer of Firebeard**

Source: *Dragonslayer: The Return* by William King

---

Now I know that King Thangrim Firebeard wielded the Hammer of Fate, but he didn't forge it or even wield it all that effectively.

So, my question is, **why do the 2 books by the same author call the same object by different names?**

Comment: Looking at the wikis on those novels it looks like you are correct; the name did change. Though there does not seem to be any info on the hammer (either name), Karag Dum, who originally conquered it, or anything else that might impact the name somehow. I do not know as much about WH:F, but in 40k it is common to rechristen and rename a weapon that has been in the possession of Chaos once it has been re/claimed. Given the name changes between books my only thought is that Felix or company was responsible for renaming the hammer,but that implies forgetting the history of it before they got it...

Comment: @Odin1806: Thanks for your research. Perhaps an explanation was given in an earlier unpublished draft?

Comment: According to wiki the books both take place very close to one another ("a few days" it said) but it is also possible the answer lies somewhere in the rest of the Gotrek and Felix series. There are a number of short stories and etc. that may shed some light... good luck!

Comment: Both in universe and out of universe, I can't find any reason for this. Possibly just a mistake on King's part. He could have just misremembered Firebeard's hammer, the Hammer of Fate as the "Hammer of Firebeard". It's not a stretch to assume a simple mistake like that could have happened. I never even noticed this myself and I've read both of those books a few times each.

Comment: Thanks @Daft. I thought you'd take an interest in the question :-). Maybe you would like to type up your research into an answer so I can upvote/accept?

Comment: @Accio_Answer I'll flesh it out a little. It's an interesting question, it's a pity I can' come up with a definitive answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been unable to find any reason, either in universe or out of universe as to why the hammer changes name. The best I can come up with are some scenarios where the name change might have occurred.

---

#### Possibly just a minor mistake by King

King could have just misremembered Firebeard's hammer, the Hammer of Fate as the "Hammer of Firebeard".

---

#### King might have decided a name change was in order

Authors for the Black Library are sometimes given free reign over their specific piece of the universe (I think less now than they used to be in King's time, around AOS at least). So King could very well have decided to rename the hammer as he saw fit.

---

#### The hammer could have multiple names

It's also not entirely unheard of for weapons in WH and 40k to have multiple names. I can't think of any off the top of my head but I'm sure I've seen it.